# Elapsed Time using TimerTick - Time Format

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, elapsedtime

I have created a real time elapsed clock that synchronizes with the computer time and is being displayed in a Label.

Now, my doubt is how to display the clock in this Label in the "hh:mm:ss" format.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ElapseStartTime = DateTime.Now
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim ElapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(ElapseStartTime)
    LB_Timer.Text = String.Format("{0} : {1} : {2}", ElapsedTime.Hours, ElapsedTime.Minutes, ElapsedTime.Seconds)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a `Stopwatch` to measure elapsed time and then get a `TimeSpan` from its `Elapsed` property. Not a huge improvement over what you have if you don't need to pause but worth knowing.

Answer (score 2):

Since [DateTime.Subtract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract) returns a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring) structure, you can use the [TimeSpan.ToString(Format)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring) method to format the output string:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    LB_Timer.Text = Date.Now.Subtract(ElapseStartTime).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
End Sub
```

When targeting a .Net Framework `< FW 4.0`, use the parameter-less, culture-insensitive `TimeSpan.ToString()` method.

```
 LB_Timer.Text = Date.Now.Subtract(ElapseStartTime).ToString().Substring(0, 8)
```

From the Docs:

> Support for formatting TimeSpan values was added in the .NET Framework
> 4. However, the ToString() method overload remains culture-insensitive. Its behavior remains unchanged from previous
> versions of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Just note that that overload of `ToString` was only added recently; .NET 4.5 I think.  If you're using an older version then you can always add the `TimeSpan` to a arbitrary `Date` and call `ToString` on the result, e.g. `(Date.Today + (Date.Now - ElapsedStartTime)).ToString("HH:mm:ss")`. Note that `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` use slightly different format specifiers.

Comment: Thanks but... it shows error "Conversion from string "hh\:mm\:ss" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

Comment: @jmcilhinney  Yes, that's true. The parameter-less `TimeSpan.ToString()` provides the same output in this case, though (tested with FW 3.5).

Comment: *Conversion from string "hh\:mm\:ss" to type 'Integer*? What Integer? Did you write what I posted (exactly, I mean)?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? I'm guessing that it's earlier than 4.0 and, just as I said, that overload of `TimeSpan.ToString` is not supported and the code is being interpreted as trying to index the result of the `ToString` method. In that case, you have been given two alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

just i found this could help! {0:**d2**}

```
LB_Timer.Text = String.Format("{0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", ElapsedTime.Hours, ElapsedTime.Minutes, ElapsedTime.Seconds)
```